# Data not inserted when form is submitted in Cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am beginner in cake php...I created page model and so on.But my data is not submitting when I click on publish button on add page form.Below is my code.Any help would be greatly appreciated..
    This is my controller function

```
   function add(){
     if(!empty($this->data)){
  if($this->Page->save($this->data)){
  $this->Session->setFlash('This Page was successfully added!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
     } else {
 $this->Session->setFlash('This Page was not added, Please try again!');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Page.php

```
class Page extends AppModel {
  var $name ='Page';
var $validate = array (
    'title' => array(
        'title_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
                'rule'=> 'notEmpty',
                'message'=> 'This Page is missing A Title!'
            ),
        'title_must_no_be_unique'=>array(
                'rule'=> 'isUnique',
                'message'=> 'A Page with the Title exists!'
            )   
        ),
    'body'=>array(
    'body_must_not_be_blank'=>array(
            'rule'=> 'notEmpty',
            'message'=> 'This Page is missing A Body text!'     
        )   
    )
);
public function isOwnedBy($Page, $user) {
return $this->field('id', array('id' => $Page, 'id' => $user)) === $Page;
```

}
}

This is View/Pages/add.ctp

```
 <div id="Page">
```

### Add New Page

```
<?php 
echo $this->form->create('Page', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->form->input('title');
echo $this->form->input('body');
echo $this->form->end('Publish');
```

?>

Comment: could you please tell us your cake version and controller name ?

Comment: I am using cake 2.3.8 and controller name is PagesController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `PagesController` comes with `$uses = array()`,

just set `$uses = array('Page')'`. May be this is creating problem here.

and also as **Guillemo Mansilla** said it should be 
`echo $this->Form->create()` instead of `echo $this->form->create()`

and also your action should be

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        if ($this->Page->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This Page was successfully added!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' = > 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This Page was not added, Please try again!');
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

The following route creates problem here.

`Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));`

since you're accessing the page via `/pages/add`. so when you submit the form it goes to `display` action instead of `add` action.

so set a route as like this `Router::connect('/add-page', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'add'));` to work the things properly.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have updated my add function but still the problem persistes and I am using this Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

Comment: `Router::connect('/add-page', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'add'));` just set the route like this and then try

Answer (score 0):

Try
    echo $this->Form->create()

instead of 
    echo $this->form->create()

In other words, mind your case.

Comment: I have changes $this->form->create() to $this->Form->create().But Still this doesnot solve my problem.

Comment: Please paste the generated HTML.